# Galois groups of quadratic number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Is there an algorithm that finds,
given a subgroup $G$ of a finite permutation group $S_n$,
a quadratic number field $K=Q(\sqrt a), a \in Q$ and a Polynom $f \in K[x]$ such that the Galois Group of the splitting field $L$ of $f$ has $Gal(L/K)=G$ or fails if no such field exists? 
Are anyhow any finite groups known that cant be Galois groups of quadratic number fields?

Comment: I am pretty sure that for fixed base fields questions like these are wide open. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem .

Comment: [All the "editing" I did was to correct the spelling of "Galois" in the title.]

Comment: If by `fails' you allow it to never stop, then yes.  Everything in sight is countable, and so you just list all possible polynomials, and check (one by one) whether they give you $G$ as the Galois group.

Conjecturally, this algorithm always terminates.

Of course, it is terrible!

Given a polynomial, it is difficult to compute the Galois group.  Conversely, it is occasionally easy to find polynomials for certain groups, but currently not for all groups (even over $\mathbb{Q}$ much less a quadratic field).

Comment: Also, the title is a little misleading: of course it is not very hard to compute the Galois groups of quadratic number fields...

Comment: by fail I meant fail after a finite time,
since quadratic number fields have a close connection wiht CM elliptic curves I think, (or naivly hope) that it might be easier to
find such extension fields than over Q, since more structure is their? Why is it nevertheless easier over Q to calculate Galois gropups? 

Comment: So you mean imaginary quadratic fields? Then the connection is through the abelianized Galois group, where these things are "easy" (i.e., class field theory). Do you see a way to produce non-abelian extensions with CM elliptic curves? By the way, $\mathbb{Q}$ also has an explicit version of class field theory with $\mathbb{G}_m$ playing the role of the elliptic curve, so your heuristic might indicate that the case of $\mathbb{Q}$ should be even *easier* than the imaginary quadratic case.

Comment: @Markus: "Why is it nevertheless easier over Q to calculate Galois gropups[sp]?"

As far as I know it is only easier in the sense that the programs I am aware of which compute arbitrary Galois groups, given a polynomial, have been programmed to work only over Q.  (But even so, these programs are incredibly slow, even for modest size degree on the polynomial.)

Comment: I learned that its not clear what finite groups occur as galois gropus over Q, the next natural case would be quadratic number fields. In case of imaginary number fields, we have with weber functions at least something that is somehow similar to what we have with exp(2kpi k/n) for Q. And there are i think even unramified curves over quadratic fields (at least sometimes) so I hoped that this quadratic case might be easier. Maybe only to exclude some finite Galois groups. this guess seems to be wrong.